# Fatal Execution Engine Error on the Windows2008 r2, IIS7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, iis-7.5

We are running some asp.net(3.5) applications on the Windows2008 r2, IIS7.5.
Recently we got some event logs so difficult, we have not idea hope some guys can help.

1.EventID: 1334 (9-1-2011 8:41:57)
Error message

An error occurred during a process host idle check.
Exception: System.AccessViolationException
Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
StackTrace:    at System.Collections.Hashtable.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.IsIdle()
   at System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.IsIdle()

2.EventID: 1023 (9-1-2011 19:44:02)
Error message

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4952 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (742B851A) (80131506)

3.EventID: 1000 (9-1-2011 19:44:03)
Error message

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bcd2b
Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.4952, time stamp: 0x4bebd49a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000c262
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13

4.EventID: 5011 (9-1-2011 19:44:03)
Error message

A process serving application pool 'AppPoolName' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '2552'. The data field contains the error number.

5.some info: 
we got the memory.hdmp(234MB) and minidump.mdmp(19.2) from control panel >> action center but I donot know how to use that :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal Execution Engine Error on the Windows2008 r2, IIS7.5](http://serverfault.com/questions/221877/fatal-execution-engine-error-on-the-windows2008-r2-iis7-5)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you narrow it down;

1. [Download & install the debugging tools for windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463016)
2. Open the memory dump with windbg
3. Goto View->Call Stack (this will bring up the call stack)
4. Got View->Command (this windows popped up by default but, you need to type into the command line)
5. ".loadby sos mscorwks"  (no quotes)
6. "!symfix"
7. ".reload -f"
8. "!CLRStack"

the last command !CLRStack should show you what was going on the .net stack when the crash happened.

You can type !Help to get help from the "SOS" dll we loaded in step 5.

Their is plenty of online references if you run into trouble.  Your developer should recognize some of the things he see's in the stack trace.

Good luck!